# lightning:input size is dynamically expanding for custom error message

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have issue with the lightning:input size. The maxlength is 5 and everything looks good. But when I set the custom validation error in my JS with the error message "CVV2 attempt failed. Please try again or select another token", The size of the input text box is expanding to the lenght of error message.

```
<lightning:layoutItem size="" padding="horizontal-small">
    <lightning:input type="text" label="CVV2" maxlength="5" id="cvv2Id".../>
</lightning:layoutItem>

<lightning:layoutItem size="" padding="horizontal-small" >
    <lightning:input type="text" label="Exp. Date" maxlength="5".../>
</lightning:layoutItem>

  showInvalidCVVMessage: function(component, event,helper){
     ...........
     var v = component.find("cvv2Id");
     v.setCustomValidity("CVV2 attempt failed. Please try again or select another token");
     v.reportValidity();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `aura:id` and not just `id`.

In lightning (aura/lwc), the ids are modified at runtime. In aura, you need `aura:id` to identify using [component.find](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm)

```
<lightning:input type="text" label="CVV2" maxlength="5" aura:id="cvv2Id" />
```

Comment: It is aura:id only. I mentioned as id initially.